# Plotting a scatter plot of X vs Y using MatPlotlib or Pandas using a third variable

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Hi IM using pandas to plot this. I am getting an error using Matplotlib that.

```
  zero_term = 0
one_term = 0
two_term = 0
for i in range(logistic_Y.shape[0]):
    if logistic_Y[i]<21.3:
        logistic_Y[i] = 0
        zero_term += 1
    if ((21.3<logistic_Y[i]) and (logistic_Y[i]<33.9)):
         logistic_Y[i]=1
         one_term += 1
    if(logistic_Y[i]>33.9):
         logistic_Y[i] = 2
         two_term +=1 

logistic_Y = pd.DataFrame(logistic_Y)
print(logistic_Y.shape)
i = X[columns[3]]
j = X[columns[2]]

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(X.origin,X.displacement, c = logistic_Y ,cmap="jet", lw=0)
plt.show
```

ValueError: 'c' argument has 392 elements, which is not acceptable for use with 'x' with size 392, 'y' with size 392.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dmD8.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNCk1.png data set
[division of X and Y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dmD8.png)

Comment: As written, your code throws an error `NameError: name 'logistic_Y' is not defined`. What does `logistic_Y` look like?

Comment: logistic_Y = np.copy(Y)
its a copy of Y, where I've converted all the values to (0,1 or 2) for classification purposes. It is  of size [ 392,1]. Similar to all columns in X

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please help us to help you. Please provide a snippet that we can actually run - try to create a minimal example showing your problem. I don't think we need that for loop - you can just take a small slice from `X`, `Y`, and `logistic_Y` and last 3 lines of code would be enough.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What's `X`? What's `Y`? What modules did you import? Please edit your question in light of the above.

Comment: that's one weird error! maybe try c = logistic_Y.values?

Comment: Can you perhaps share the first 10 elements of `X.origin` `X.displacement` and `logistic_Y`? Without looking at the data, it's hard to find the error

Comment: I would try `c = logistic_Y.flatten()`. But as others said, please always provide a [mcve] when asking a question here.